# FindBy annotation used to find a list of WebElements

Tags: c#, list, selenium, webdriver

In java I use code like this to grab a list of WebElements with the same identifier:

```
@FindBy(how = How.CLASS_NAME, using = "name")
private List<WebElement> names;
```

Now, I'm using c# and I'm trying to do the same thing using:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "name")]
private List<IWebElement> names;
```

However, this gives the exception:

> System.ArgumentException: Object of type
>   'Castle.Proxies.IWrapsElementProxy_1' cannot be converted to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement]'.

I've tried FindAllBy and FindBys, however those do not seem to be valid. Is there anyway I can do this besides

`names = getDriver().findElements(By.ClassNames("..."))`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of 2.29.0 of the .NET bindings, this is [now no longer true](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG). The `FindsBy` attribute now will find individual elements or collections of elements. Note that the collection field or property decorated by the `FindsBy` attribute must be of type `IWebElement` or `IList<IWebElement>` in order to be populated by the `PageFactory`. Any other type will throw an exception.

Comment: `IList<IWebElement>` did it for me, I tried using `List<IWebElement>` and `IEnumerable<IWebElement>` naively thinking that they would implement `IList` - oh how wrong I was.

Answer (score 1):

Try `[FindAllBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "name")]` instead.

Comment: Does not seem to work, I get the error:
Type "FindAllBy" could not be found, I also tried FindBys

Comment: Which version of WebDriver are you using?

Comment: Use 
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(""));