# What is the equivalent C# version of Java Webdriver @Findby?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I'm moving from a Java environment to .NET and need to write Webdriver tests using a page object model.

In Java I would use the following annotation:

```
@FindBy(linkText = "More details")
WebElement moreDetailsButton;
```

Please would someone be able to tell me how to define a WebElement using C#? Also, is the PageFactory.initElements used the same way?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: This has been answered before, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592455/findby-annotation-used-to-find-a-list-of-webelements

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren, not quite, that question is specifically about a `List` of `IWebElement`'s and also the question is so old it's now deprecated - there is a direct translation for this attribute in the .NET API.

Comment: Well if you read more then the first paragraph of that question you can see that there is a solution to FindBy in the first answer.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren, they are two totally *different* questions, and there is *no code example* in that question - which OP is *directly asking for*!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is a direct translation.

You are looking for `FindsBy`:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.LinkText, Using = "More details")]
private IWebElement moreDetailsButton;
```

As for the `PageFactory.initElements`, yes, it's a very similar thing in .NET, *usually* called in the constructor of the Page Object:

```
public class LoginPage
{
    private IWebDriver _driver;

    public LoginPage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
        PageFactory.InitElements(_driver);
    }
}
```

Note, that the Selenium project is entirely open source. You can easily see the source the Page Objects 'helper' classes [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/dotnet/src/support/PageObjects).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just managed to answer my own question at the same time here [link](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html)